# MVC Validator.TryValidateObject does not validate custom atrribute, validateAllProperties = true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, data-annotations

When calling `Validator.TryValidateObject` with `validateAllProperties = true` my custom validation attribute does not get triggered. The `ValidationResult` does not contain an entry for my erroneous property value. Below is the model, attribute and code used to test this.

```
//Model
public class Model
{
    [AmountGreaterThanZero]
    public int? Amount { get; set; }
}

//Attribute
public sealed class AmountGreaterThanZero: ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string errorMessage = "Amount should be greater than zero.";

    public AmountGreaterThanZero() : base(errorMessage) {  }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if ((int)value <= 0)
            {
                var message = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                return new ValidationResult(message);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if ((int)value < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

//Validation Code
var container = new Container();
container.ModelList = new List<Model>() { new Model() { Amount = -5 } };
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(container, null, null);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var modelIsValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(container, validationContext, validationResults, true);
```

**Note:** That the validation works fine and `ValidationResult` returns with correct error message if I use the `TryValidateProperty` method.

**Edit:** As suggested by @Fals and the approach i took was to validate each object in the list individually.

Comment: Did you overrided IsValid method? This will tell if its valid or no!

Comment: @Fals yes if you look at the code snippet provided you can see the exact implementation with IsValid overriden. As mentioned when `TryValidateProperty` is applied it works, but it wont validate the objects in a collection.

Comment: There's a method public bool IsValid(object value), you should override this one as well!

Comment: @Fals updated the code in the questions above. This does not seem to resolve the issue. validating the container doesn't seem to validate the objects in the model list collection.

Comment: Hi, i saw now, you trying to pass the list of object, but the method knows how to validade every object, not a collection of it! Thats the problem, you must pass object by object to validade!

Comment: @Fals thanks for this, that is what I am doing now. So will mark this as the answer. I am just wondering what happens under the hood when the model is validated when passed through a controller action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking the comment by @Fals as the answer as this is the approach i ended up taking. As there was no other question answered that satisfied my original question.

> @Fals - Thats the problem, you must pass object by object to validade!